# Install Firebase iOS SDK in a Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to install Firebase SDK in a Cocoa Touch framework I'm developing. When I tried it manually and noticed that Cocoa Touch frameworks don't have the 'Other Linker Flags' under linking so I couldn't set the -ObjC flag and it didn't build.
So gave it go via cocoa pods but the project won't build, apparently because Firebase SDK has references to UIKit and AppDelegate. 
Any idea on how to set a library which includes Firebase SDK or another way around it?
Thank you

Comment: What's the purpose behind the latter? Are you trying to create a dependency based on firebase that you want to include in other projects?

Comment: @JadGhadry Exactly. I would like to build my own frameworks for business logic and services then add them via carthage to the main project which will deal only with UI. For this framework I'd like to write only my firebase logic.